# Determine the convergenece/divergence of an improper integtal

Tags: calculus, improper-integrals

The improper integral is as follows:    $$\int_{3}^{\infty}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{x^3-9} }$$

Please help determine whether divergent or convergent , I couldn't solve it.

Comment: Do you know if $\displaystyle \int \limits _0^\infty \dfrac{1}{t^{3/2}}\mathrm dt$ converges? Can you make a connection between your integral and this one?

Comment: lets say f1 : $\frac{dx}{\sqrt{x^3-9} }$ > f2: $\frac{1}{t^(3/2)}$ , but f2 is convergent so this is inconclusive

Comment: Remember that you have to integrate $f_2$ from $0$ to infinity

Comment: @MathDisease what you missed is that though $f_1\gt f_2$, $f_1=\Theta(f_2)$. does that help?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici the question has the lower limit equal to $3$ though? what am i missing?

Comment: The integrand is regular in x=3 so only the behaviour in infinity is left. There it behaves as x^(-3/2), which is integrable. So the integral exists as a finite quantity.

Comment: Sorry ! Iwas reading $x^2$ instead of $x^3$

Answer (score 0):

There is only one potential problem:

Around $\infty$:
$$
\frac 1{\sqrt{x^3-9}}\sim \frac 1{x^{3/2}}
$$ and $$\int_3^\infty \frac {dx}{x^{3/2}}=\lim_{A\to\infty}
[-2x^{-1/2}]_3^A<\infty
$$

Now,
$$
\frac 1{\sqrt{x^3-9}}\sim \frac 1{x^{3/2}}$$
and those are positive so$$
\exists A>0 \ \ x>A\Rightarrow  \frac 1{\sqrt{x^3-9}}\le \frac 2{x^{3/2}}
$$
$$
\int_3^\infty \frac {dx}{\sqrt{x^2-9}} \le
\int_3^A \frac {dx}{\sqrt{x^2-9}}+  \int_3^\infty \frac {dx}{x^{3/2}}<
\infty
$$

Comment: @Daniel Fischer thank you, correction made.

Comment: Even though in $$\frac 1{\sqrt{x^3-9}}\sim \frac 1{x^{3/2}}\Rightarrow
\left[\exists A>0 \ \ x>A\Rightarrow  \frac 1{\sqrt{x^3-9}}\le \frac 2{x^{3/2}}\right]$$ both the consequent and the antecedent are true, the consequent is not a consequence of the antecedent.

Comment: if $f\sim g>0$ then $f = g+o(g)$ so for $x$ large enough the $o(g)$ term is $\le g$ and $\exists A \ \ x>A\Rightarrow f(x)\le g + g$, don't you think?

Comment: What is your definition of $g\sim h$? To me it means $\lim \frac g h=1$, it doesn't matter which function is greater.

Comment: to me it means $f = g+o(g)$. It does not require that $g\neq 0$ ;) and btw, we also have $g\le 2f$ for $x$ large.

Comment: OK, in any case $o (g)$ can be negative.

Comment: here, everything is positive.